# VBA: Count times a pair of values appears

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, count

To generate from this:

[image]

that:

[image]

I have this piece of code:

```
Sub missing()
Dim ws, wsOut As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Table1")
Set wsOut = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("output")

lastRow = ws.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowOut = wsOut.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 1 To lastRow
    If (ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = "") _
    And _
    ((ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Peking") Or _
    (ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Tokio") Or _
    (ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = "London")) _
    And _
    ((ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = "A") Or _
    (ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = "B") Or _
    (ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = "C")) _
    Then
        wsOut.Range("B" & lastRowOut & ":C" & lastRowOut).Value = ws.Range("G" & i & ":H" & i).Value
        wsOut.Range("A" & lastRowOut).Value = i
        lastRowOut = lastRowOut + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I tried to implement a code to generate in addition this output marked in red:

[image]

So what I'm trying is to count and list every pair that occures. I tried to implement "countifs" into the if-statement but it failed. The actual table has over 40 entries in "City" and over 10 entries in "Departement" and over 6.000 entries in total. Would be happy if someone can help me out with this. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Have you considered to create a simple Pivot table?

Comment: Yes, I had suggested it.. Unfortunately I have to implement it in the code.

Comment: You do realise you can implement a simple Pivot table in the code? :-)

Comment: @Dominique thanks for your advice, I appreciate that! But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention in your comment, you seem not to know how to record a macro: you go to the "Developer" ribbon (you might need to enable it first) and in the first part, you click "Record macro" and you just start doing what you want to record (in this case, insert a pivot table).

I've just done that, using a range "A1:B8" as input and creating the kind of pivot table you are looking for, and the following code gets created automatically (beware that this is automatically added code, which has a lot of superfluous lines, parameters, ...: it's ok to use it as a starting point but it's very useful trying to learn from it by modifying, deleting, ... parts of it):

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R8C2", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Sheet1!R2C4", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(2, 4).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("City")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Dep")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Dep"), "Count of Dep", xlCount
End Sub
```

By the way: as you can see from the name "PivotTable3", I did not succeed from my first attempt :-)

Answer (score 1):

No VBA required.

Formula in `E2` is `=SORT(UNIQUE($B$2:$C$18),{1,2},{1,1})`
Formula in `G2` is `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$18,INDEX(E2#,,1),$C$2:$C$18,INDEX(E2#,,2))`

[image]

**VBA Solution:**
Result in the test procedure will hold your values, or can be used on a worksheet as `=SORT(CountCities(B2:C18),{1,2},{1,1})` to get same result as my first solution.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyDataRange As Range
    Set MyDataRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C18")

    Dim Result As Variant
    Result = CountCities(MyDataRange)

End Sub

Public Function CountCities(Target As Range) As Variant

    Dim UniqueValues As Variant
    UniqueValues = WorksheetFunction.Unique(Target)
    ReDim Preserve UniqueValues(1 To UBound(UniqueValues), 1 To 3)
    
    Dim itm As Long
    For itm = 1 To UBound(UniqueValues)
        UniqueValues(itm, 3) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Target.Columns(1), UniqueValues(itm, 1), Target.Columns(2), UniqueValues(itm, 2))
    Next itm
    
    CountCities = UniqueValues

End Function
```

Everything in one procedure:

```
Public Sub Missing()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1")
    
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("output")
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim lastRowOut As Long
    lastRowOut = wsOut.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 7), ws.Cells(lastRow, 8))
    
    Dim UniqueValues As Variant
    UniqueValues = WorksheetFunction.Unique(Target)
    ReDim Preserve UniqueValues(1 To UBound(UniqueValues), 1 To 3)
    
    Dim itm As Long
    For itm = 1 To UBound(UniqueValues)
        UniqueValues(itm, 3) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Target.Columns(1), UniqueValues(itm, 1), Target.Columns(2), UniqueValues(itm, 2))
    Next itm
    
    Dim wsOutRange As Range
    Set wsOutRange = wsOut.Cells(lastRowOut, 2).Resize(UBound(UniqueValues), 3)
    
    wsOutRange = UniqueValues
    With wsOut.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=wsOutRange.Columns(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=wsOutRange.Columns(2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range(wsOutRange.Address)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

New code not using `Unique` function:

```
Public Sub Missing()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1")
    
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("output")
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim lastRowOut As Long
    lastRowOut = wsOut.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 7), ws.Cells(lastRow, 8))
    
    'New code
    '''''''''
    Dim tmpCol As New Collection
    Dim rw As Range
    For Each rw In Target.Rows
        On Error Resume Next
        tmpCol.Add rw, rw.Cells(1) & rw.Cells(2)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next rw
     
    Dim UniqueValues As Variant
    ReDim UniqueValues(1 To tmpCol.Count, 1 To 2)
    
    Dim lCntr As Long
    For lCntr = 1 To tmpCol.Count
        UniqueValues(lCntr, 1) = tmpCol(lCntr).Cells(1).Value
        UniqueValues(lCntr, 2) = tmpCol(lCntr).Cells(2).Value
    Next lCntr
    'End of new code
    ''''''''''''''''
    
    'UniqueValues = WorksheetFunction.Unique(Target)
    ReDim Preserve UniqueValues(1 To UBound(UniqueValues), 1 To 3)
    
    Dim itm As Long
    For itm = 1 To UBound(UniqueValues)
        UniqueValues(itm, 3) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Target.Columns(1), UniqueValues(itm, 1), Target.Columns(2), UniqueValues(itm, 2))
    Next itm
    
    Dim wsOutRange As Range
    Set wsOutRange = wsOut.Cells(lastRowOut, 2).Resize(UBound(UniqueValues), 3)
    
    wsOutRange = UniqueValues
    With wsOut.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=wsOutRange.Columns(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=wsOutRange.Columns(2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range(wsOutRange.Address)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! unfortunately i do need to implement it to the code.

Comment: Have updated with code solution.

Comment: Thank you! I'm struggling with implementing this code from yours to the code I posted. Would be great if everything goes all in one procedure.

Comment: Have added it all as a single procedure.  I take it `Table1` is a worksheet and not an Excel table (ListObject).

Comment: I don't know why but I get the runtime error 438.

Comment: On which line does the error occur and which version of Excel are you using?  `Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)` might mean some of the worksheetfunctions aren't available in your version... maybe.

Comment: Excel 2016 (16.0.5332.1000)

Comment: Does it happen on this line `UniqueValues = WorksheetFunction.Unique(Target)`?  Not sure if 2016 has the `Unique` function.

Comment: None of the lines are marked and I just read that the function should is not supported by Excel 2019, 2016 and earlier.

Comment: Have added code that doesn't use `Unique` - may not be the best solution, but it works.

Comment: Have you updated the code? Looks similar to before.

Comment: @ErenJaeger I did.... not sure where my edit's gone.  Got this horrible feeling I've updated a different post.... and now that original poster is wondering what the hell I posted.

Comment: Have added the code again - no idea what happened first time.

Answer (score 1):

### Count Column Pairs (Dictionary)

- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountColumnPairs()
    
    ' 1. Define (adjust) constants.
    
    ' s - Source (read from)
    Const sName As String = "Table1"
    ' Designate the first and second unique column of the range.
    Dim suCols() As Variant: suCols = VBA.Array(2, 3) ' switch for fun
    
    ' d - Destination (write to)
    Const dName As String = "Output"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    ' Designate the position of the unique columns (1, 2)
    ' and the count column (0).
    Dim dCols() As Variant: dCols = VBA.Array(1, 2, 0) ' switch for fun
    Const dCountColumnTitle As String = "Appears ""x"" Times"
    
    ' 2. Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' 3. Write the source data to arrays.
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    ' Reference the source range ('srg') ...
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' ... and write its number of rows to a variable ('srCount').
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Write the values from the unique columns
    ' to 2D one-based (one-column) arrays ('sData1', 'sData2').
    Dim sData1() As Variant: sData1 = srg.Columns(suCols(0)).Value
    Dim sData2() As Variant: sData2 = srg.Columns(suCols(1)).Value
    
    ' 4. Write the unique values and their count to a dictionary ('dict').
    '    In the dictionary, the 'keys' ('Key1') will hold the unique values
    '    from the first unique column, while each corresponding 'item'
    '    ('dict(Key1)') will hold another dictionary whose 'keys' ('Key2')
    '    will hold the values from the second unique column,
    '    while each corresponding 'item' ('dict(Key1)(Key2)')
    '    will hold the count.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' main
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitivity ('A=a')
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = 1 '
    
    Dim Key1 As Variant
    Dim Key2 As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        Key1 = sData1(sr, 1) ' first column
        If Not dict.Exists(Key1) Then
            Set dict(Key1) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dict(Key1).CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitivity ('A=a')
        End If
        Key2 = sData2(sr, 1) ' second column
        If Not dict(Key1).Exists(Key2) Then drCount = drCount + 1 ' total count
        dict(Key1)(Key2) = dict(Key1)(Key2) + 1 ' each count
    Next sr
    
    ' 5. Write the values from the dictionary
    '    to the destination array ('dData').
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    Dim dcUpper As Long: dcUpper = UBound(dCols)
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = dcUpper + 1
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
        
    ' Write the headers.
    
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim dc As Long
    Dim Key1Written As Boolean
    
    For dc = 0 To dcUpper
        Select Case dCols(dc)
        Case 0
            sValue = dCountColumnTitle
        Case 1
            sValue = sData1(1, 1)
        Case 2
            sValue = sData2(1, 1)
        End Select
        dData(1, dc + 1) = sValue
    Next dc
    
    ' Write the data.
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 1 ' headers are already written
    
    For Each Key1 In dict.Keys
        For Each Key2 In dict(Key1).Keys
            dr = dr + 1
            For dc = 0 To dcUpper
                Select Case dCols(dc)
                Case 0
                    sValue = dict(Key1)(Key2)
                Case 1
                    sValue = Key1
                Case 2
                    sValue = Key2
                End Select
                dData(dr, dc + 1) = sValue
            Next dc
        Next Key2
    Next Key1
    
    ' 6. Write the results to the destination.
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('dws')...
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    ' ... and clear its cells.
    dws.UsedRange.Clear
    ' Reference the first row of the destination range.
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, dcCount)
        ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
        .Resize(drCount).Value = dData
        ' Apply simple formatting.
        .Font.Bold = True ' first row
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit ' entire columns
    End With
    
    ' Save the workbook.
    'wb.Save
    
    ' 7. Inform to not wonder if the code has run or not.
    
    MsgBox "Column pairs counted.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm sorry, this goes beyond my understanding for VBA. If I run this code I get the error '13' and nothing is underlined.

Comment: Feel free to download [my working file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LYtL8muACDH-_NCFMy5mtcJF0jnYm1YO/view?usp=sharing) from Google Drive. If your source data's layout is presented in the first image, you need to replace the appropriate two lines with `Dim suCols() As Variant: suCols = VBA.Array(1, 2)` and `Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("G1").CurrentRegion`. If your source data's layout is presented in the third image, you need to replace the appropriate two lines with `Const sName As String = "Output"` and `Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "E1"`.